# How can I delete a row from a database with C#?

Tags: c#, database

How can I delete a row from a database with C#?

First I show the table content in a `GridView`, and I want to know how to delete the row I selected in the `GridView` (when I press the delete button) from the database.

Comment: Do you *really* want to permanently delete the column from the database or do you just want to hide it in your gridview?

Answer (score 3):

I think he means "row" not column.

If your grid is bound to a DataTable with a DataAdapter then you can call dataSet.dataTable.Rows[x].Delete() and then dataAdapter.Update() to reflect changes in DB.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13(VS.80).aspx)

In order to find out what x is (which row has the "arrow" as yout put it) check
[this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DBGridCurrentRow.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a column is not possible.   You can delete a row ...

If you want to delete a column, you'll have to ALTER the table, and DROP the column, but I don't think that you will want your users to be able to do that ...

Perhaps you just want to hide the column in your GridView ?